# How to align HTML buttons with links?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align an input button with a link (class "button"), but in Safari and Chrome there is like 1 pixel difference at the top and I can't figure out why.

[image]

```
<input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Enrol" />
<a href="#" class="button" id="cancel">Cancel</a>

input.button {
  height: 38px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #4D28B2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
}
a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4D28B2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Should also include your HTML code.

Comment: You can see the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/R2Jzk/

Comment: There is an even bigger difference in Firefox. Bear in mind that browsers have default styling for buttons, which you would need to reset with a CSS reset stylesheet.

Comment: I checked both elements with the inspector and they have the same values for padding, margin and height. There shouldn't be a problem with resets in this case, no?

Comment: Well for once I have different fonts for the two objects (Times New + Arial) which directly result from the default styling - there might be more hidden things ;-)

Comment: Fonts are set globally. I just tried Eric Meyers CSS reset, with no change in the display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the padding, set the heights to the same value, adjust the vertical align on both, and then do box-sizing for all the browsers.

Here's a link to a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/cjXcp/5/

And the code:

```
input.button {
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    background: #4D28B2;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4D28B2;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This code could be reduced in verbosity, but you get the idea.

Comment: Never thought it would be so difficult to let a link look like a button, but thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: It's because weird defaults are set to buttons and inputs that aren't set to other elements. It often operates on a unique box model.

Answer (score 2):

Appending **float:left;** to both elements fixes this problem in Chrome and Firefox.
You may also add **margin-left:2px;** to **.button** to restore the missing gap between the buttons when using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

One possible culprit is excess whitespace. Different browsers interpret indentation and line-breaks in HTML differently. You should output all your HTML through a whitespace-stripping function. (as a bonus, it could also save bandwidth)

This is what I do, though it doesn't play nice with JavaScript:

```
function ob_compress_html($str)
    {
    return preg_replace(array('{>\s{2,}<}', '{^\s+}', '{\s+$}D'), array('><'), $str);
    }

ob_start('ob_compress_html');
```